# ggplot, fill much more visible on graph than legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha

I have a graphing question that I feel I should know the answer to, but I can't quite figure it out. I've specified 2 different fill colors & have made a legend of it, but when I generate the graph, the fill colors are either...

1. way too bright on the graph, but just the right in the legend
2. just right on the graph, but not even visible in the legend

It looks like this has to do with the 'alpha' value I specify, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help is appreciated!

#My graphing code

```
#graph the average output by machine
ggplot(data=tempdf1)+
  #dot plot of individual POD machines
  geom_point(aes(x=sample,y=mean_perc_FAM_to_ref,color=POD_machine),width=0.1)+
  #line plot of the mean across POD machines
  stat_summary(aes(x=sample,y=mean_perc_FAM_to_ref,group=known_conc,color=POD_machine),fun=mean,geom="line")+
  #wrap by known conc
  facet_wrap(.~known_conc,scales="free")+
  #ref box for 10% variation from known trait conc
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=p10xmin-1,xmax=p10xmax+1,ymin=p10ymin,ymax=p10ymax,fill="10% Error"),alpha=0.005)+
  #ref box for 5% variation from known trait conc
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=p5xmin-1,xmax=p5xmax+1,ymin=p5ymin,ymax=p5ymax,fill="5% Error"),alpha=0.005)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("5% Error"="green","10% Error"="yellow"))+
  #labels
  labs(x="Sample",y="Measured % of Trait",color="POD Machine",fill="Error Range")+
  #clean up background, add gridlines (only to y-axis), add x- and y-axis lines
  theme(panel.background=element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid=element_line(color="black"))+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())+
  theme(axis.line=element_line(color="black"))+
  #customize x-axis so there is no space between graph and y-axis
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  #customize tick marks in y-axis
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

When I specify "alpha=0.005" for geom_rect, this is the graph I get
[image]

When I specify "alpha=0.5" for geom_rect, this is the graph I get
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use something like `scale_fill_manual(values=c("5% Error"="green","10% Error"="yellow"), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))`.

Comment: Also, I would plot the rectangles first (i.e. move them up to be the first layer), so that the points and lines are plotted on top. You are probably also overplotting the rectangles a bunch of times, which is why you need such a small alpha value (0.005) to get them to be only a little transparent.

Comment: I think @Axeman's second point in the second comment should be addressed: you are plotting each rect `nrow(tempdf1)` times, whereas you likely just want to plot one rect for each facet and error range (five times each rect-color). Two options: (1) create a new frame that is provides just 1 row per `known_conc` per error range; or (2) use `geom_rect(..., data=...)` and subset the data so that you don't have repeated calls. (I think #1 is more likely testable and confirmable than the latter, over to you.)

Comment: I agree with @r2evans, and specifically the new data.frame option. Also, you can just use `-Inf` and `Inf` as the `xmin` and `xmax` values for the rectangles.

Comment: Ah, thank you all, rearranging the geom_rect to earlier in the script fixed the issue. I was unaware that I was re-plotting the geom_rect multiple times, that's quite helpful to know.